# How do i add style to a widgets child sibling in GWT

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap

How do i add style to a widgets child sibling in GWT

if suppose if the html of an object ObjParent be like this

```
<li>
<a class="" href="javascript:;">
<i></i>
<span class=""> Some Text </span>
</a>
</li>
```

Consider the above code is constructed by a widget ObjParent

with only ObjParent, how do i set the style for the span some text

i tried `ObjParent.getWidget(0).getElement().getChild(0).addStyleName("style1");`

but it showed error as addStyleName cant be added to node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Method `#addStyleName(String)` is only available for Widgets. To set a class on an Element use `#addClassName(String)`. You can directly cast a Node to an Element:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
...
Node node = objParent.getWidget(0).getElement().getChild(0);
Element element = (Element) node;
element.addClassName("style1");
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome suggestion. It saved my 2 cents!